# Issue in Update query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables called `PassengerPaymentDetails` and `RoomInfo`. Following is the query that I used to extract some values from existing `PassengerPaymentDetails` table.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Count, RequestReference, RoomTypeID, RoomCategory 
FROM 
    [UL_SLHEV].[dbo].[PassengerPaymentDetails]   
WHERE
    Status != 0 
GROUP BY 
    RoomTypeID, RoomCategory, RequestReference
```

As you can see I have `RoomTypeID`, `RoomCategory` and `Count` in the above mentioned table.

Following screenshot has the `RoomInfo` table:

I want to update the `RoomInfo` table data from the extracted `Passengerpaymentdetails` table. I can map these two tables with the `RequestReference`.

Need to update the count value in `RoomInfo` table according to the `Passengerpaymentdetails` table count value. Can anybody please help?

**UPDATE:**

Following is the code that I have tried so far. It is correctly return join table. I don't know how to set the value to the `RoomInfo` table with the getting table. And also here I am using left join for some purpose. I want to insert the value as well if the left table contains new row with the new `roomtypeId`. otherwise if the right table contains the same `roomtypeID` update the `roomInfo` with the updated value from `passangerpaymentdetails` table.

```
SELECT 
t1.RequestReference as RoomInfoReq, 
t1.Count as RoomInfoCount, 
t1.RoomTypeID as RoomInfoID,
t1.RoomCategory as RoomInfoRoomCat,
l.RequestReference as PassangerReq, 
l.Count as PassangerCount, 
l.RoomTypeID as PassangerRoomTypeID, 
l.RoomCategory  as PassangerRoomCategory

FROM (
select 
count(*) as Count, 
RequestReference, 
RoomTypeID, 
RoomCategory 
FROM
[UL_SLHEV].[dbo].[PassengerPaymentDetails]  
where 
Status!=0 group by RoomTypeID, RoomCategory, RequestReference) 

as t1
Left JOIN RoomInfo as l on 
t1.RequestReference = l.RequestReference and
t1.RoomTypeID = l.RoomTypeID and 
t1.RoomCategory = l.RoomCategory and
 l.Status!=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that. It would be good if you provide DDL and DML instructions to test that, however you can see the logic how to do that:

```
UPDATE ri
SET [COUNT] = rd.[COUNT]
FROM RoomInfo ri
JOIN (SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Count], RequestReference, RoomTypeID, RoomCategory 
FROM 
    [UL_SLHEV].[dbo].[PassengerPaymentDetails]   
WHERE
    Status != 0 
GROUP BY 
    RoomTypeID, RoomCategory, RequestReference) rd ON rd.RoomTypeID = ri.RoomTypeID
    AND rd.RoomCategory = ri.RoomCategory
    AND rd.RequestReference = ri.RequestReference
```